# JQuery or JavaScript to alert on button click if selection not made

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a button that when clicked points you to another html page.  I am stuck currently on a click event that I am not sure to use javascript or jquery on.  Pretty much, when I click and there is no item in the select tag selected, then show the alert pop up.  Else, proceed to the normal navigation to the next page. Any feedback is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showDangerAlert").click(function() { 
    $(this).show(); $(this).hide(); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showDangerAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="text-align: center">
    You have not selected a Delivery Option! Please choose one to proceed.
</div>

<select id="colorselector" class="custom-select d-block mb-3">
  <option value="red">Select...</option>
  <option id="shipToAddress" value="yellow">Ship to Address</option>
  <option id="inStorePickup" value="blue">In-Store Pickup</option>
</select>

<div id="yellow" class="colors">
  <a href="shoppingCart.html" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mb-3 cartLink">
    Add to Cart 
    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="blue" class="colors">
  <small class="mb-3">You will select your desired store during   
    <strong>checkout.</strong>
    <span> 
      <a href="#" data-target="#storeListing" data-toggle="modal"> 
        <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> 
        See available stores near you.          
      </a>
    </span>
    <a id="inStorePickupRedirect" href="shoppingCart_inStorePickup.html" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto my-3 cartLink">
      Add to Cart 
      <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
    </a>
  </small>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so we can help you?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#showDangerAlert").click(function() {
                $(this).show();
                $(this).hide();

            });
        });

Comment: I deleted other attempts, sorry.  But all I wanted to do is to evaluate the selection and if none are selected, show the error, else if one is selected, then proceed as normal

Comment: `$(this).show(); $(this).hide();`??

Comment: @Jeto I deleted other attempts without saving.  I am just seeking direction on this.

Comment: You are trying to attach an `onclick` listener to the message `#showDangerAlert` but you want to validate when the user clicks on `#inStorePickupRedirect` isnt that? Also you will need something to really makes the validation, like an `if`, just `show()` then `hide()` an element makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an click event using JQuery and check if the user has done some selection to the select. If user has select something do the navigation using javascript.

```
$('#button').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('#selector_id').val() != no_selected_value) {
       window.location = "/your_page";
    } else {
       $('#showDangerAlert').show();
    }
});
```

So no_selected_value in your case should be red/yellow or blue.

---

**EDIT**

I've done some changes in your code snipped to work as I've explained above.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showDangerAlert").hide();
  $("#showDangerAlert").click(function() { 
    $(this).hide(); 
  });
});

$('#button').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('#colorselector').val() != 'red') {
       window.location = "/shoppingCart.html";
    } else {
       $('#showDangerAlert').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showDangerAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="text-align: center">
    You have not selected a Delivery Option! Please choose one to proceed.
</div>

<select id="colorselector" class="custom-select d-block mb-3">
  <option value="red">Select...</option>
  <option id="shipToAddress" value="yellow">Ship to Address</option>
  <option id="inStorePickup" value="blue">In-Store Pickup</option>
</select>

<div id="yellow" class="colors">
  <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mb-3 cartLink">
    Add to Cart 
    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="blue" class="colors">
  <small class="mb-3">You will select your desired store during   
    <strong>checkout.</strong>
    <span> 
      <a href="#" data-target="#storeListing" data-toggle="modal"> 
        <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> 
        See available stores near you.          
      </a>
    </span>
    <a id="inStorePickupRedirect" href="shoppingCart_inStorePickup.html" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto my-3 cartLink">
      Add to Cart 
      <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
    </a>
  </small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If there is no option selected then this will alert no option selected
>   else you can do whatever you want. This same code can work with
>   JavaScript, just need to change selectors.

```js
$("#btncheck").on("click",function(){
      if($("#mySelect")[0].selectedIndex <= 0){
        alert("No Option Selected")
      } else {
        alert("Option Selected")
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="1">First</option>
      <option value="2">Second</option>
      <option value="3">Third</option>
      <option value="4">Fourth</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="btncheck" value="check"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showDangerAlert').show();
  $("#colorselector").change(function() { 
  var sel = $("#colorselector option:selected").val();
    if(sel=='red') {$('#showDangerAlert').show();} else {$('#showDangerAlert').hide();}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showDangerAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="text-align: center">
    You have not selected a Delivery Option! Please choose one to proceed.
</div>

<select id="colorselector" class="custom-select d-block mb-3">
  <option value="red">Select...</option>
  <option id="shipToAddress" value="yellow">Ship to Address</option>
  <option id="inStorePickup" value="blue">In-Store Pickup</option>
</select>

<div id="yellow" class="colors">
  <a href="shoppingCart.html" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mb-3 cartLink">
    Add to Cart 
    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="blue" class="colors">
  <small class="mb-3">You will select your desired store during   
    <strong>checkout.</strong>
    <span> 
      <a href="#" data-target="#storeListing" data-toggle="modal"> 
        <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> 
        See available stores near you.          
      </a>
    </span>
    <a id="inStorePickupRedirect" href="shoppingCart_inStorePickup.html" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto my-3 cartLink">
      Add to Cart 
      <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
    </a>
  </small>
</div>
```